# Question on the proposition 12.3 in Tu's Introduction to Manifolds: The tangent bundle $TM$ of a manifold $M$ is second countable

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

> Claim: The tangent bundle $TM$ of a manifold $M$ is second countable

> Proof: Let $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a countable basis for $M$ consisting of coordinate open sets. Let $\phi_i$ be the coordinate map on $U_i$. Since $TU_i$ is homeomorphic to the open subset $\phi_i(U_i)\times \mathbb{R}^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and any subset of a Euclidean space is second countable, $TU_i$ is second countable. For each $i$, choose a countable basis $\{B_{i,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ for $TU_i$. Then $\{B_{i,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a countable basis for the tangent bundle.

I don't quite understand the "punchline" of the proof, i.e. why is $\{B_{i,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ a countable basis for the tangent bundle $TM$? Do we represent $TM$ as a union over the elements $TU_i$, so that $\bigcup_{i,j=1}^\infty B_{i,j}$ is thus a basis for $TM$, and by some other result the countable union of countable unions is a countable union?

Comment: There is a little typo: It should be $\{B_{ij} \}_{i,j}$. I'm not sure which step precisely confuses you. Yes, the $B_{ij}$ form a basis by construction (and if this is not clear, then you should try to write out the definition of a basis and convince yourself of it). The collection $\{B_{ij} \}_{i,j}$ is a countable collection since the index set is $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ which is countable.

Comment: @QiZhu I suppose that my question was really whether the countable union of a countable union is still countable (which it is). Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The countable union of countable sets is indeed countable, though this does require a weak version of the axiom of choice.